# how to simulate loop in turbo prolog

Tags: loops, prolog

I want to compute the summation of odd numbers in a given range like 1 to 9 is the given input. and my program will show the summation of all odd numbers between 1 to 9. Though the task is so simple theoriticaly, but as a starter of turbo prolog, I can't handle the loop to compute the summation. Any help would be appreciating..

Advance thanks.

Comment: Thanks @lurker for adding the tag.

Comment: @lurker: since this question is not specific to Turbo-Prolog, it's better to remove it.

Comment: @false the title is "how to simulate loop in **turbo prolog**". I took that to mean Turbo Prolog specific, which could have quite a different answer than if it was for "normal" Prolog since Turbo Prolog tends to do many things differently.

Comment: @lurker, but you know that there is nothing specific in Turbo-Prolog in that regard. Beginners often include the name of the system they are using: that's fine, since they do not know whether or not that is relevant. We know. And thus we should retag accordingly such that future users will profit.

Comment: @false well, truly, I don't know Turbo Prolog well enough to know if it has it's own looping feature. I do know that, from what I've seen of Turbo Prolog, it aligns little with most other Prologs. Specifically, I didn't think that it has the `foreach`, `between`, etc, that other Prolog implementations have. So if one poses a nice answer with `foreach`, it's not an answer for the Turbo Prolog user. Maybe I'm totally wrong on that, and TP does have it. To your point, though, I should have followed my first instinct for a comment, which was to ask, "Does it have to be Turbo Prolog?".

Comment: Yes I want to know this implementation specific for TP. @lurker

Comment: @false thanks, I'm seeing this in a different light at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write the full solution for you, but can give an idea how to "loop" through a summation in a general way. Looping in Prolog is often done through recursion. The recursion gets around the fact that Prolog will not let you reinstantiate a variable within the same predicate clause once it's instantiated (unless you backtrack). The following is ISO Prolog syntax.

```
sum_values(First, Last, Sum) :-
    sum_values(First, Last, 0, Sum).

sum_values(First, Last, Sum, Sum) :-
    First > Last.
sum_values(First, Last, Acc, Sum) :-
    First =< Last,
    NewAcc is Acc + First,
    NewFirst is First + 1,
    sum_values(NewFirst, NewAcc, Sum).
```

The first clause sets up an accumulator starting at the value 0.

The second clause handles the normal recursive case where the first value does not exceed the last. The first value is added to the accumulator to create an updated accumulator, and the "first" value is incremented to create a new first value. The recursive call to `sum_values` computes the rest of the sum with the new accumulator.

The last (third) clause unifies the final sum with the accumulator when the first value finally exceeds the last.

Note that I could have implemented this without introducing the accumulator, but then I wouldn't have the *tail recursion* which can be optimized (if desired) by the Prolog system. The non-accumulator version looks like this:

```
sum_values(First, Last, 0) :- First > Last.
sum_values(First, Last, Sum) :-
    First =< Last,
    NewFirst is First + 1,
    sum_values(NewFirst, Last, PartialSum),
    Sum is PartialSum + First.
```

This is a little shorter, but there's no tail recursion that can be refactored.

Modifications you would need to make for your problem (these are ones I'm aware of, as I'm only a little familiar with some of TP's syntax):

- Replace `is/2` with `=/2` (I think TP uses `=/2` for expression evaluation)
- You might have to replace `=<` with `<=` (I don't recall which one TP likes)
- Check that `First` is odd. If it's not, you need to skip adding it to the accumulator.

You could also do an initial check for odd `First` and if it's not odd, increment it to form a new `First`, then proceed doing a summation incrementing by 2 through the recursion instead of by 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, It might be helpful @lurker